# Is it possible to throw exceptions while deserializing json value using JsonbDeserializer?

Tags: java, jsonb

I'm trying to throw bad request exception when empty value is passed for LocalDate in the request by using JsonbDeserializer. I'ved tried following.

```
public class LocalDateDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<LocalDate> {   

private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ERA, 1)
        .toFormatter()
        .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE)
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctx, Type rtType) {
        try {
            String stringDate = jsonParser.getString();
            if (stringDate != null) {
                return LocalDate.parse(stringDate, FORMATTER);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Provided date is not valid");
        }
    } 
}
```

But instead of Bad Request Exception I'm getting Internal server exception.
can anyone explain the reason for this? how can i get Bad Request exception instead of internal server exception?

Error Log :

```
2022-05-11 17:21:32,120 SEVERE [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller] (default task-1) Provided date is not valid
2022-05-11 17:21:32,121 ERROR  (default task-1) Error occurred : javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Internal error: Provided date is not valid
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-json-binding-provider@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonb.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:92)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-crypto@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:36)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:198)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:338)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Internal error: Provided date is not valid
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:93)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-json-binding-provider@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonb.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:84)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: Provided date is not valid
    at deployment.core-engine-api.war//com.machnetinc.platform.jsonb.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:40)
    at deployment.core-engine-api.war//com.machnetinc.platform.jsonb.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.UserDeserializerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(UserDeserializerDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.deserializeNext(ObjectDeserializer.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson//org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:68)
    ... 79 more
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the wrong exception? I think the answer is there.

Comment: I was expecting to show the error message in the response. I've added the error log if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this problem by implementing an `ExceptionMapper` to catch the `ProcessingException`. First, I tried to implement an `ExceptionMapper` for `JsonbException` but later realized that `JsonbException` was further wrapped by `ProcessingException`. Using `ExceptionMapper` for `ProcessingException` to catch the exception and then mapping to `BadRequest` Response solved the issue.

```
@Provider
public class ProcessingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ProcessingException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ProcessingException exception) {
       String defaultMessage = "Unable to process request body";
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                       .entity(defaultMessage)
                       .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                       .build();
    }
}
```